# CMTimeGetSeconds crash app

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8

I use **AVPlayer** to play video link and add observer to update progress bar. But with the video which have time more than 10s, my app get crash. Below is my code

- Play video button press:

  ```
  @IBAction func playVideoButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
      if let contentUrl = curVideoModel?.video_Content_Url{
          player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: contentUrl))
          player?.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.None
          playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
          playerLayer!.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.imvVideoThumbnail.frame.size.width, self.imvVideoThumbnail.frame.size.height)
          playerLayer!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
          playerLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
          self.playvideoHolderView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
          NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "itemDidFinishPlaying:", name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: player?.currentItem)
          player?.addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval(CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1.0/60.0, Int32(NSEC_PER_SEC)), queue: nil, usingBlock: { (time) -> Void in
              self.updateProgressbar()
          })
          player!.play()
      }
  }
  ```
- The function call back when video finish play:

  ```
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: player?.currentItem)
  self.progressBar.progress = 0
  if notification.name == AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification{
      if player != nil{
          player?.pause()
      }
      if playerLayer != nil{
          playerLayer!.removeFromSuperlayer()
      }
  }
  ```
- And the function to update progressbar:

  ```
  var duration: Double
  var time: Double
  if player != nil{
       duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(player!.currentItem.duration)
       time = CMTimeGetSeconds(player!.currentTime())
  } else{
      duration = 0
      time = 0
  }
  self.lblTotalTime.text = "\(Int(duration))"
  self.lblCurrentTime.text = "\(Int(time))"
  self.progressBar.progress = Float(time / duration)
  ```

[image]
**P/S: It crash on real device(iPod touch iOS 8.3). But play OK on simulator**

**EDIT:** Maybe the comment of Peter is right. I check: **if player!.currentItem.duration.value > 0** before get: **duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(player!.currentItem.duration)** .Then the crash is fixed**

Comment: Can you get a the application to crash properly and past the stack trace here?

Comment: Swift on Xcode 6.4 so stupid when debug and log the stack trace. So, I get nothing of log.

Comment: I got no real experience with Swift but it looks like you have a "exception breakpoint" set?

Comment: Nope, doesn't have exception breakpoint set

Comment: Then its pretty hard to debug from here. I would put a breakpoint just prior to the crash and examine whet player! and player!.currentaitem and player!.currentItem.duration is. What happens if i double is set to NaN in swift? usually before you call CMTimeGetSeconds you check for CMTIME_IS_VALID() and !CMTIME_IS_INDEFINITE().

Comment: cannot get what you mean, can you explain in detail?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86678/discussion-between-lee-and-peter-segerblom).

Comment: CMTimeGetSeconds() return NaN(not a number) if the CMTime you pass in is not valid or indefinite. In objective-c it won't be a problem in the assignment phase but maybe that will throw a exception in swift? Other than that can currentItem be nil?